# UTC offset error when installing the Sensenet Service package via SQL Server Authentication

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, datetimeoffset, sensenet

For the last couple of days, I've been trying to install the sensenet service package via SQL Sever Authentication. Previously, I was able to successfully install the package through Windows Integrated Security but opted for SQL Server Authentication. Sensenet as of now only supports MS SQL databases and so that is what I went with. I created a free tier MS SQL database in AWS RDS without any preference of timezone, availability zone(us-east-1 but did not specify if I wanted 1a, 1b, 1c etc) and everything set to default. Reading from the docs, it says that by default it sets my timezone to be UTC and in my console, the created timezone for my db instance is GMT-400 . The timezone in my local machine is set to Eastern Standard Time(UTC-05:00). Now this is where the problem occurs.

After following the steps to install the service package and build the solution, I went to the bin folder to where the SnAdmin.exe is in, opened my command prompt in Administrator mode and typed this:

```
\snadmin install-services dataSource:some-amazon-endpoint.com initialCatalog:someDatabase 
username:usernameToLoginInServer password:passwordToLoginInServer dbusername:nameOfUserInSomeDatabase 
dbpassword:passwordOfUserInSomeDatabase
```

All of these variables are needed for SQL Server Authentication to be activated. This is the stacktrace that I got after entering execution phase 2.

```
ApplicationException: Phase terminated with error: The UTC time represented when the offset is applied must be between year 0 and 10,000.
Parameter name: offset
   at SenseNet.Packaging.PackageManager.ExecuteCurrentPhase(Manifest manifest, ExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\BuildAgent\_work\63\s\src\ContentRepository\Packaging\PackageManager.cs:line 165
   at SenseNet.Packaging.PackageManager.Execute(String packagePath, String targetPath, Int32 currentPhase, String[] parameters, TextWriter console) in E:\BuildAgent\_work\63\s\src\ContentRepository\Packaging\PackageManager.cs:line 71
   at SenseNet.Tools.SnAdmin.SnAdminRuntime.ExecutePhase(String packagePath, String targetDirectory, Int32 phase, String[] parameters, String logFilePath, Boolean help, Boolean schema) in E:\BuildAgent\_work\63\s\src\Tools\SnAdminRuntime\SnAdminRuntime.cs:line 191
---- Inner Exception:
ArgumentOutOfRangeException: The UTC time represented when the offset is applied must be between year 0 and 10,000.
Parameter name: offset
   at System.DateTimeOffset.ValidateDate(DateTime dateTime, TimeSpan offset)
   at System.DateTimeOffset..ctor(DateTime dateTime)
   at SenseNet.ContentRepository.Storage.Caching.SnMemoryCache.Insert(String key, Object value, CacheDependency dependencies) in E:\BuildAgent\_work\63\s\src\Storage\Caching\SnMemoryCache.cs:line 49
   at SenseNet.ContentRepository.Storage.DataBackingStore.CacheNodeHead(NodeHead head, String idKey, String pathKey) in E:\BuildAgent\_work\63\s\src\Storage\DataBackingStore.cs:line 136
   at SenseNet.ContentRepository.Storage.DataBackingStore.GetNodeHead(Int32 nodeId) in E:\BuildAgent\_work\63\s\src\Storage\DataBackingStore.cs:line 65
   at SenseNet.ContentRepository.User.get_Administrator() in E:\BuildAgent\_work\63\s\src\ContentRepository\User.cs:line 47
   at SenseNet.ContentRepository.Security.DesktopAccessProvider.get_CurrentUser() in E:\BuildAgent\_work\63\s\src\ContentRepository\Security\DesktopAccessProvider.cs:line 36
   at SenseNet.ContentRepository.Storage.Security.AccessProvider.ChangeToSystemAccount() in E:\BuildAgent\_work\63\s\src\Storage\Security\AccessProvider.cs:line 45
   at SenseNet.ContentRepository.Security.DesktopAccessProvider.GetCurrentUser() in E:\BuildAgent\_work\63\s\src\ContentRepository\Security\DesktopAccessProvider.cs:line 52
   at SenseNet.ContentRepository.Storage.Security.AccessProvider.ChangeToSystemAccount() in E:\BuildAgent\_work\63\s\src\Storage\Security\AccessProvider.cs:line 45
   at SenseNet.ContentRepository.RepositoryInstance.DoStart() in E:\BuildAgent\_work\63\s\src\ContentRepository\RepositoryInstance.cs:line 141
   at SenseNet.ContentRepository.RepositoryInstance.Start(RepositoryStartSettings settings) in E:\BuildAgent\_work\63\s\src\ContentRepository\RepositoryInstance.cs:line 107
   at SenseNet.ContentRepository.Repository.Start(RepositoryStartSettings settings) in E:\BuildAgent\_work\63\s\src\ContentRepository\Repository.cs:line 55
   at SenseNet.Packaging.Steps.StartRepository.Execute(ExecutionContext context) in E:\BuildAgent\_work\63\s\src\ContentRepository\Packaging\Steps\StartRepository.cs:line 55
   at SenseNet.Packaging.PackageManager.ExecuteCurrentPhase(Manifest manifest, ExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\BuildAgent\_work\63\s\src\ContentRepository\Packaging\PackageManager.cs:line 112

===============================================================================
SnAdmin stopped with error.
```

**Quick Workaround**

Changing the local time zone in my machine to UTC got rid of the error. This is not ideal because I would like it to use the correct timezone that my machine automatically applies. I'm just confused as to why it fails when my timezone is EST as I'm not sure if this has to do with sensenet or AWS itself. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We think the issue was that we used the incorrect DateTime max value when inserting an object to the cache. The fix is already published in [version 7.4.1](https://github.com/SenseNet/sensenet/releases/tag/v7.4.1) where we use the DateTimeOffset max value.

Comment: Interesting, will have to test it out. When this error occurred I had 7.4.0 installed on my machine but had to roll back to 7.3.4 for it to work. Will be letting you know if it worked at some point.

Comment: Just letting you know that I'm using 7.4.1 and the issue seem to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I searched the net far and wide for any information related to this problem. Though I am installing sensenet in a slightly different way I thought this may be of help. I am installing sensenet 7.4 using the nuget sensenet.services.install in an mvc project.
I had a similar problem during installation.

```
15:41:24.9333   startIndexingEngine: False
15:41:24.9333   indexPath: C:\Users\username\Source\repos\demo\demo\App_Data\LocalIndex
15:41:28.7483   ApplicationException: Phase terminated with error: The UTC time represented when the offset is applied must be between year 0 and 10,000.
Parameter name: offset
   at SenseNet.Packaging.PackageManager.ExecuteCurrentPhase(Manifest manifest, ExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\BuildAgent\_work\63\s\src\ContentRepository\Packaging\PackageManager.cs:line 165
   at SenseNet.Packaging.PackageManager.Execute(String packagePath, String targetPath, Int32 currentPhase, String[] parameters, TextWriter console) in E:\BuildAgent\_work\63\s\src\ContentRepository\Packaging\PackageManager.cs:line 71
   at SenseNet.Tools.SnAdmin.SnAdminRuntime.ExecutePhase(String packagePath, String targetDirectory, Int32 phase, String[] parameters, String logFilePath, Boolean help, Boolean schema) in E:\BuildAgent\_work\63\s\src\Tools\SnAdminRuntime\SnAdminRuntime.cs:line 191
---- Inner Exception:
ArgumentOutOfRangeException: The UTC time represented when the offset is applied must be between year 0 and 10,000.
Parameter name: offset
   at System.DateTimeOffset.ValidateDate(DateTime dateTime, TimeSpan offset)
   at System.DateTimeOffset..ctor(DateTime dateTime)
   at SenseNet.ContentRepository.Storage.Caching.SnMemoryCache.Insert(String key, Object value, CacheDependency dependencies) in E:\BuildAgent\_work\63\s\src\Storage\Caching\SnMemoryCache.cs:line 49
   at SenseNet.ContentRepository.Storage.DataBackingStore.CacheNodeHead(NodeHead head, String idKey, String pathKey) in E:\BuildAgent\_work\63\s\src\Storage\DataBackingStore.cs:line 136
   at SenseNet.ContentRepository.Storage.DataBackingStore.GetNodeHead(Int32 nodeId) in E:\BuildAgent\_work\63\s\src\Storage\DataBackingStore.cs:line 65
   at SenseNet.ContentRepository.User.get_Administrator() in E:\BuildAgent\_work\63\s\src\ContentRepository\User.cs:line 47
   at SenseNet.ContentRepository.Security.DesktopAccessProvider.get_CurrentUser() in E:\BuildAgent\_work\63\s\src\ContentRepository\Security\DesktopAccessProvider.cs:line 36
   at SenseNet.ContentRepository.Storage.Security.AccessProvider.ChangeToSystemAccount() in E:\BuildAgent\_work\63\s\src\Storage\Security\AccessProvider.cs:line 45
   at SenseNet.ContentRepository.Security.DesktopAccessProvider.GetCurrentUser() in E:\BuildAgent\_work\63\s\src\ContentRepository\Security\DesktopAccessProvider.cs:line 52
   at SenseNet.ContentRepository.Storage.Security.AccessProvider.ChangeToSystemAccount() in E:\BuildAgent\_work\63\s\src\Storage\Security\AccessProvider.cs:line 45
   at SenseNet.ContentRepository.RepositoryInstance.DoStart() in E:\BuildAgent\_work\63\s\src\ContentRepository\RepositoryInstance.cs:line 141
   at SenseNet.ContentRepository.RepositoryInstance.Start(RepositoryStartSettings settings) in E:\BuildAgent\_work\63\s\src\ContentRepository\RepositoryInstance.cs:line 107
   at SenseNet.ContentRepository.Repository.Start(RepositoryStartSettings settings) in E:\BuildAgent\_work\63\s\src\ContentRepository\Repository.cs:line 55
   at SenseNet.Packaging.Steps.StartRepository.Execute(ExecutionContext context) in E:\BuildAgent\_work\63\s\src\ContentRepository\Packaging\Steps\StartRepository.cs:line 55
   at SenseNet.Packaging.PackageManager.ExecuteCurrentPhase(Manifest manifest, ExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\BuildAgent\_work\63\s\src\ContentRepository\Packaging\PackageManager.cs:line 112

15:41:28.9122   ===============================================================================
15:41:28.9132   SnAdmin stopped with error.
```

Based off of "Luis Averhoff's" work around, I found that if you are installing using this method; you can complete the install by setting your local clock to utc - 1 (Budapest time)

I am looking into a solution that does not require this work around, but for now this will enable you to install sensenet.

Comment: I think OP is posting a solution and not asking a new question. It could be better worded but he's saying that the workaround is: *"you can complete the install by setting your local clock to utc - 1"*

Comment: @brasofilo That is correct. I apologize if my wording could be better. Even though Luis Averhoff Installed sensenet In a slightly different way, the errors where almost Identical. Sense the way I installed is the same way as the tutorial, I thought It would be helpful to include my findings here; instead of making a whole new post stating "I found a problem here is how to fix it".

Answer (score 0):

I could not comment, so I am posting this here. I had to set the time to straight up UTC without the offset. The difference may have something to do with DST and your location.  In any case, I thought this might help someone.  Hopefully the developer knows about this (I will try to contact them to make sure).

Edit: Posted issue on [github](https://github.com/SenseNet/sensenet/issues/505).